# Getting profiling results with VS2010: C# API vs vsperfcmd

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiling, code-coverage, profiler

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms_joc/archive/2005/04/08/406608.aspx) has the info about how to run profiler as the following batch file

```
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:run.coverage
hello
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

into C# code

```
 // A guid is used to keep track of the run
 Guid myrunguid = Guid.NewGuid();
 Monitor m = new Monitor();
 m.StartRunCoverage(myrunguid, "run.coverage");


 // TODO: Launch some tests or something
 // that can exercise myassembly.exe

 // Complete the run
 m.FinishRunCoverage(myrunguid);
```

For the `TODO:` part, I used this code

```
p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "hello.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
// Look at return code – 0 for success
if (p.ExitCode != 0) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error in profiling");
    System.Environment.Exit( -3 );
}
```

The code runs fine, but I can't the profiled result I did with running batch file.

This is the result from running batch file which has all the info.

[image]

This is the result from C# code which doesn't have profiled info, but only schema
[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: There's a word missing from your final sentence "..I can't ? the profiled result...".  What is the missing word?  It's important :)

Comment: @Elroy : I elaborated the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have no idea,really, but are you running with admin privs?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question to [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/889ec60f-3838-47c1-866a-9ff110b39a21), and it seems like the method doesn't work.